# Using pthreads with Dev-C++ - Odd Error

Tags: c, pthreads, dev-c++

trying to get a feel for pthreads and multithreaded programming in C. Ive managed, thanks to this site, to get the library linked so that it no longer gives me errors in the compiling.

Im trying to get 2 threads running, one that prints 1000000 x's and one that prints 1000000 o's.

There is a problem, however, when running the program. The command line pops up for a millisecond and then dies, nothing seems to happen. Not even any compile errors or anything that i can then fix. If i comment out the thread creation and thread join statements then the command line pops up and waits for a key to be hit because of the system("PAUSE").

here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* printChar(void *c);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;

    pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,printChar,"x");
    pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,printChar,"o");

    pthread_join(thread1,NULL);


  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}

void* printChar(void *c)
{
      char *str;
      str = (char*)c;
      int i;
      for(i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
      {
              printf("%c",str);
      }
}
```

I'm running a DOS C-application from the Bloodshed Dev-C++ IDE. My version of the pthread .dll and .a files are: libpthreadGC2.a and pthreadGC2.dll

If you need any other specs lemmie know

thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using DevC++? It is an unmaintained pile of pooh. Use Code::Blocks at http://codeblocks.org/

Comment: Try running it from a command line console to see the error.

Comment: Not only it is unmaintained but includes a severely outdated gcc (3.x).

Comment: What I don't understand is where people are picking up that DevC++ is a good IDE from, and then when they use it still think that. I remember downloading it, running it and saying "you have got to be f*cking joking", and then deleting it.

Comment: i appreciate the comments guys,

im gonna give Code::Blocks a try :) i will let you know how it goes

Comment: oh one question though, @Neil , does Code::Blocks support a C compiler too? or just C++?

Comment: @user It supports both C and C++.

Comment: sweet tits! thanks so much @Neil. Code::Blocks is running fine and my multithreading works. TY!

Comment: Here's the obligatory http://www.jasonbadams.net/20081218/why-you-shouldnt-use-dev-c/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your printf: format ‘%c’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’. So it should be printf("%s",str);